# System for self-evaluation and practice of mathematics

Tags: gratis, web-apps, educational, latex

I'm looking for a package to implement a small online learning environment.

The public are new students at our university who may want some extra classes in mathematical topics. There are two parts:

- First the student fills out a multiple choice test which measures the current knowledge. Based on the result of the test and the curriculum of the student a suggestion is made which extra classes to take.
- Then, after each of the classes the student has taken, he or she would be able to exercise: for each exercise that appears the student would be able ask for a hint and to check if the answer is correct.

Extra requirements:

- Free.
- Has to support LaTeX to display mathematical equations.
- An account for each user so they can keep track over their process (this would be nice but is not mandatory).

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

[Moodle](https://moodle.org/) has [quizzes](https://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Quiz_module) and [TeX](https://docs.moodle.org/20/en/TeX_notation_filter) support.

It requires a fair amount of effort to set up, however.